# Koa2 session page view count 2 times for each update

Tags: koa2

When you load the first time, it shows correctly. After, each update gets 2 page view count, not one.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const session = require('koa-session');
const app = new Koa();
app.keys = ['Shh, its a secret!'];
app.use(session(app));

app.use(async function(ctx) {
  let n = ctx.session.views || 0;
  ctx.session.views = ++n;
  console.log(`times= ${n}`);

  if (n === 1) {
    ctx.body = 'Welcome here for the first time!';
  } else {
  ctx.body = `You visited this page ${n} times!`;
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I testet it right now and it seems to work correctly. What you have to consider, is, when typing your URL in the browser, some browsers already try to preload things. This also happened here.

What I then tried to be sure, that it works as expected: I shutted down the node/koa app, then in the browser cleared the session for that side (Developertools - Storage - Sessions), started node/koa app again and then on client side hit reload several times. Here, on server side I gut the correct output:

```
times= 1
times= 2
times= 3
times= 4
times= 5
```

and on client side the output was also correct.